# setting base64 encoded src into plugin jquery

Tags: jquery

i have recently bought a plugin named **Lollipop** image editor for editing my images, it is working well with static images but i am facing issue of using it with base64 encoded images!

i basically have a gallery on which users can upload images so after uploading phase i have a magic icon to open editor and edit the image this is how the plugin is working right now

**HTML**

```
<div class="item-masonry box"><img src="images/demo-img.jpg">
                            <div class="buttons"><a class="btn share-btn facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u="><i class="fa fa-facebook-official"></i></a><a class="btn share-btn pinterest" href="https://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url="><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i></a>
                                <a
                                        class="btn magic"><i class="fa fa-magic"></i></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

**jquery**

```
 window.$(".magic").each(function () {
            window.$(this).on("click", function () {
                var img = window.$(this).parents().siblings("img");
                imageEditor.open({
                    image_url: img[0].src
                }, img[0]);
            });
        });
```

now i have the image in base64 format and i want the plugin to accept in the image in the base64 format here is my html

**html**

```
<div class="images">
                                <input type="file" class="images-input" id="images_file_8"/>
                                <label for="images_file_8">
                                </label>
                                <div class="active-content">
                                    <h5>Main Picture</h5>
                                </div>
                                <div class="div-count">
                                    <h6 order="8">08</h6>
                                </div>
                                <div class="options">
                                    <i class="fas fa-magic"></i>
                                    <i class="fas fa-sync-alt"></i>
                                    <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="progressbar"></div>
<div class="block-image">
<img src="data:image/jpeg,base64,/......."/>
</div>
                            </div>
```

now this is what i have tried so far

```
  window.$(".magic").each(function () {
            window.$(this).on("click", function () {
 var img = $(this).parents("images").find("img");
                imageEditor.open({
                    image_url: img[0].src
                }, img[0]);
            });
        });
```

but it is throwing an error

```
Cannot read property 'src' of undefined
```

is there a way we can pass base64 encoded image src?

Comment: If you already use jquery, you can use `img.attr('src')` instead of `img[0].src`

Comment: i tried saying url is undefined!

Comment: I think something related to `imageEditor`

Comment: it maybe right now it is picking up static images url so i was thinking  perhaps the issue might be something with image being in base64 format